# CustomAdapter Not Working

Tags: android, custom-adapter

every body I am developing a App in which i am getting a issue ( in-fact no nay issue but doesn't work).I am using adapter here

```
      menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
    //Cursor  cursor = dh.rawQuery("SELECT _id, item_id, item_type , item_name,Item_cost FROM temp_menu WHERE item_name LIKE ? AND Item_cost LIKE ? ",new String[]{"%","%"});

    Cursor cursor = dh.query(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_temp, null,"item_name=?", new String[] {"Apple"}, null,null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    CustAdpt custadapter = new CustAdpt(this, cursor);
    menuList.setAdapter(custadapter);
```

Custdpt is my custom-adapter. This my code of custom-adapter

```
     public class CustAdpt extends CursorAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Cursor cursor, c;
    View convertView;
    private String str_item_id;
    private String str_item_type;
    private String str_item_name;
    private String str_item_cost;
    ViewHolder holder;
    SQLiteDatabase dh = DatabaseHelpereKOT.getInstance().getDb();
    public CustAdpt(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
        cursor = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.setImType((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.veg_nv_image));
        holder.setTvTitle((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name));
        holder.setTvPrice((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_cost));
        holder.getTvTitle().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
        holder.getTvDescription().setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost")));
        int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        view.setTag(R.id.item_name, _id);
        int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_type")); 
        if (type == 1) {
            //holder.getImType().setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.non_veg);
        } else {  
            holder.getImType().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.veg);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        c = cursor;
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_data_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        ((ImageView) (convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.main_body_item_title_second_pics)))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // System.out.println(view.getTag());
                        addToDB(holder.getId());
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "insertDataOrder method", 2000).show();
                        System.out.println("i m in ryt [palce");
                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    }
    void addToDB(Integer objId) {
        if (objId != null) {
            int _id = objId;
            Cursor cursor = dh.query(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_temp,
                    new String[] { "_id", "item_id", "item_type", "item_name",
                            "Item_cost"},"_id=?", new String[] { String
                            .valueOf(_id) }, null, null, null);
            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                    && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                str_item_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_id"));
                str_item_type = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("item_type"));
                str_item_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name"));
                str_item_cost = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("Item_cost"));
                ContentValues orderValues = new ContentValues();
                orderValues.put("item_id", str_item_id);
                orderValues.put("item_type", str_item_type);
                orderValues.put("item_name", str_item_name);
                orderValues.put("Item_cost", str_item_cost);
                dh.insert(DatabaseHelpereKOT.RESTAURANT_menu_order, null, orderValues);
                String msg = "Menu Item Added Successfully";
                Message msgObject = new Message();
                msgObject.what = 1;
                msgObject.obj = msg;
                addMenuItemHandler.sendMessage(msgObject);


            }
        }
    }
    public Handler addMenuItemHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                System.out.println("inside handler");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();  
            }
        };

    };
}
```

This is my structure of database-

```
              "create table "
                    + RESTAURANT_menu_temp
                    + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,item_id TEXT , item_type TEXT , item_name TEXT , Item_cost DOUBLE)",
                    "create table "
                    + RESTAURANT_menu_order
                    + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,item_id TEXT , item_type TEXT , item_name TEXT , Item_cost DOUBLE)",
```

My xml file which is used in CustAdpt.java file is as follow

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/veg_nv_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/non_veg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_cost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/add_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add_item_order" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now this is all code where i am getting problem. Now i am going to describe . First of all data are coming dynamically json format . I parse all these json and save it to sqlite database. I did all these above step successfully . Now i trying to retrieve all these data from database to my emulator with help of Custom Adapter . I am using Custom Adpter because , in app i have to add button in each row and on each button click i have to perform different task.  But i ma stuck with problem that data is not retrieve or showing in list-view . I am nor getting any exception neither any error , it is just logical mistake. I am new in android world .so please take me out of this problem.Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: that's a lot of code. what is the problem where do you get stuck or do you get exceptions?

Comment: @Raghunandan...Thanks for your response...i ma getting any error or exception...this code is not doing any thing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is problem of cursor. May be data is not storing in data base.check your cursor.

Comment: yes... your right.this was problem of cursor. I solved this problem 2 days ago.,, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

replace `menuList.setAdapter(adapter);` with  `menuList.setAdapter(custadapter );` You are attaching wrong object.

Comment: @Vikram...yup this is mistake in just posting this questing i am getting same problem still..